# iPhone: Using Alerts to Help Debugging

Tags: iphone, notifications, alert

I've been building a rather complex system and there's come the time now where I want more concise debugging. I would like to display the contents of a variable (for this example an `NSString` called `v_string`) in a notification window (the kind of window that appear when you receive an SMS text).

Is there an easy way to just call an alert with a variable?

Thanks in Advance,

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NSLog`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog) does not do? If not (like if you need to debug an application running on a disconnected device), you can extend the `UIAlertView` with a category:

```
@implementation UIAlertView (Logging)

+ (void) log: (id <NSObject>) anObject
{
    NSString *message = [anObject description];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[self alloc] initWith…];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

And then in code:

```
NSString *anInterestingString = …;
[UIAlertView log:anInterestingString];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you build the string to display in the alert window, simply append your variable's string represenation using `stringByAppendingString`.

Answer (score 0):

Alert window is cumbersome.  Use NSLog instead:

```
NSLog(@"Variable is: %@", v_string);
```

And in Xcode's console you will see that text.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Debug String" message:v_string delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[message show];
[message release];
```

I think this way you can see what you want.
But, as zoul said, why not to use NSLog(@"my var: %@", v_string); ?

Hope that it helps.